# php input date html 5

Tags: php, html, date

first at all thanks for reading.

I have a situation here with input type date, the thing is that when i want to fill the input value i receive the format error

The specified value '06/02/2015' does not conform to the required format, 'yyyy-MM-dd'.

I tried several formats but no one works.

```
<input type="date" name="u_fecha_nac" class="form-control datepicker" value="<?= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($information['medico']['u_fecha_nac'])) ?>">
```

i'd appreciate if someone can help me with that =)

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just DB format works perfectly.

```
<input type="date" name="u_fecha_nac" class="form-control datepicker" value="<?= $information['medico']['u_fecha_nac'] ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input data-date-format="DD/MM/YYYY" type="text" readonly="readonly" name="u_fecha_nac" class="form-control datepicker" value="<?= date('d/m/Y', strtotime($information['medico']['u_fecha_nac'])) ?>">
```